# Object used for particle render getting direction flipped when particle system applied to target with curve modifier

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

Im trying to setup a modular conveyor for animation using the method shared here: [Setup Constraints for modular conveyor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172266/setup-constraints-for-modular-conveyor). However the object used to render the particles is getting its direction flipped halfway round the curve. This results in the ends not matching up.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? The blend file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NhFCWagqGgqmeIzKiUXtK5v0dvbQJeUD).

Comment: is your curve in a single part and cyclic (i.e. closed loop)?

Comment: Also please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ in order to attach blend files. It ensures the link does not expire.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with  your blend file but the "Beltlink" object  and "Segments" collection do not appear in the Outliner and are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Bruno yup .. How do you do that? It's weird. MrQuery: you've come up with something I've never encountered before, presumably because of my routine for constructing rigs at the origin, no rotations, etc. So thanks, this has pointed something up for me. Have fixed the problem, will edit the original answer.

Comment: Nevermind the beltlink, it may have been linked from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172271/35559 for some updates or possible fix.

Meanwhile, not really sure what's happening but even on a simple non cyclic curve, you can see the beltlink flipping orientation as it moves along the Y axis as soon as it reaches a curve control point (which is aligned and "flat"). May be a bug, something linked with the way curve control points are impacting the Array Modifier...

For some reason, it does not behave that way on all control points.

[image]

Comment: My bad, I've fixed the problem in the [original answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172271/35559).. sorry, it shouldn't have got through in the first place.

Comment: I think it's probably [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), internally?