# Help with conveyer belt

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, physics

I make a conveyer belt with a cube falling on top of it, but the cube don't go in the right direction. Why the cube goes backwards?

video of the problem:
https://youtu.be/UZCRaiNwiiE

cube settings:

[image]

conveyer belt settings:

[image]

Comment: have you checked out https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208604/111042 that is very step-by-step?

Comment: He explain step by step how to make the conveyer belt, but don't resolve my problem.

Comment: I would suggest that you supply your blend file: https://blend-exchange.com/  edit your question with the resulting text supplied after your upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a working one to compare [image]