# Make chain move along path

Tags: animation, path

I have a chain made with array, curve modifiers on a path and I want to make it move along the path. [image]

Comment: Should be able to just move it along the curve deformation axis-- X by default.  Depending on how you have everything set up, I suppose.

Comment: If you want to make sure the links are not deformed, something like https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147098/35559, or maybe a search here on 'Tank Tracks'