# Why my mesh is deforming using curve? I want it to be stationary and plain cube?

Tags: animation, curve-modifier

All scale are set to default which is 1, What I'm trying to do here is to make an escalator but I need a concept first so I'm trying to do it with a cube but it is not stationary I want it to be no deformation but just to follow the curve. No Deformation, No Rotation, only the location if that is possible?

Comment: Is a vertical variation on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147098/35559) what you're looking for? If not, an illustration would really help clarify your question..

Comment: Might also be interested in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve/165691#165691

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a *Curve* modifier to an object, the object will deform. What you can do is create a single vertex, give it an *Array* modifier (with the *Constant Offset* option) and a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Also in the *Object panel > Instancing*, enable *Vertices*:

[image]

Parent your stair step to the vertex object, the step will duplicate:

[image]

This works if the step stays straight, if the step is supposed to rotate on Z you'll need to use another method.